# Ansible iosxr_command save the output even when command syntax error

Tags: ansible, cisco

When using iosxr_command module to send arbitrary command to cisco device and save output, how can I keep the output even when the device return command syntax error, instead of considering task as failed?

Playbook:

```
- name: run command and save output
  iosxr_command:
    commands: 
      - "invalid syntax command"
    register: output
```

Expected saved output:

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:IOSXR_ROUTER#invalid syntax command
                              ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Instead of:

```
TASK [run command and save output] 
*****************************************************************************************************************
failed: [IOSXR_ROUTER] (item=invalid syntax command) => {"changed": false, "item": "invalid command", 
"msg": "invalid syntax command\r\n\r      
^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\nRP/0/RSP0/CPU0:IOSXR_ROUTER#"}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the [`ignore_errors: yes` task keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task)?

Comment: @mdaniel I've tried then I still need to edit the playbook to use content of output.msg instead of output.stdout when the command is failed to excute, then I got what I want. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As @mdaniel adviced I tried using ignore_errors: yes in task then I modify playbook a bit so it will capture output.msg instead of output.stdout when the command is syntax error. Like this:

```
- name: run show command
  iosxr_command:
    commands: 
      - invalid command
  register: output
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Check previous task fail
  set_fact:
    captured_data: "{{output.msg}}"
  when: output.failed

- name: Check previous task succeed
  set_fact:
    captured_data: "{{output.stdout[0] | replace('\\n', '\n')}}"
  when: not output.failed
```